# How to set the width and height rule for featured image

Tags: images, featured-post

I want to know how to make rules to re-size the images for `featured image`? I am uploading an image in `featured image` section but it is not cropping the images in exact width and height for all the images. I need `(width:100 X height:140)`. So how to do that? Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can set default site for featured images using [`set_post_thumbnail_size()`](http://queryposts.com/function/set_post_thumbnail_size/) or request different registered size by providing it as argument in [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_post_thumbnail/) call.

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress, you can set the width and height of the thumbnail image by:

```
the_post_thumbnail(array(270,270));
```